# PHP: Extract ID from a href search by name

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, href, extract

Is it possible to use preg_match (or any other way) to get the ID (after #) from a list like bellow?

Example:
Search:**datadata**
Echo (its ID): **num0035586039**

```
<a href="page1.html#num0035583725">name1</a>
<a href="page30.html#num0035584494">othername</a>
<a href="page55.html#num0035584859">word</a>
<a href="page132.html#num0035585496">wordname</a>
<a href="page133.html#num0035586039">datadata</a>
<a href="page203.html#num0035586647">fsdfasfas</a>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$dataArray=array('<a href="page1.html#num0035583725">name1</a>','<a href="page30.html#num0035584494">othername</a>');

$data='';
foreach($dataArray as $row){
    if (strpos($row, 'othername') !== false) {
        $whatIWant = substr($row, strpos($row, "#") + 1);
        $newData=substr($whatIWant, 0, strpos($whatIWant, '"'));
        echo $newData;
    }
}
```

Your output is the id you are looking for.

Edit: I set 2 links inside the array so my code is looking in the whole array trying to match the value you want (name1). When it finds it then moves on to tirmming. The output of course is the id. If there are 2 ore more hrefs that match your searching critiria it will print their ids (so it's not limited to 1).

Edit: To get the whole link that you matched your search simple go for :

```
 if (strpos($row, 'othername') !== false) {
        echo htmlspecialchars($row);
//the rest of the code
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
But, how can I get only the line where the name1 is?

Comment: Sorry. I hit enter by mistake before finish the sentence.

Comment: Ok so to understand your question those hrefs how do you get them in your php code? as array fields? as strings? I just set it up as a normal string to show you how to trim it.

Comment: The search for the word will be done on several long pages with links like the one I posted above. From extracting the ID of the word, I'll make other extractions from other files.

Comment: Have a look. I updated my code to work more "dynamic" based on what you want.

Comment: Thank you, pr1nc3. Can I ask something? As you can see, all those lines has a similar structure (<a href="page203.html#num0035586647">fsdfasfas</a>). Changing the page number, de id after '#' and the word printed on the page. So, forgetting a little bit the trimming (that you already showed), is that possible to get only the line (the whole line = <a href="page203.html#num0035586647">fsdfasfas</a>) where I make a search for the word 'fsdfasfas' (for example) ?

Comment: Of course. under the if loop if you echo the $row you will get the full line. 

Edit: I get when you mean you want to be displayed as a string not html. Give me some time.

Comment: Update my answer have a look also. You get the full link also. If i answered your question don't forget to accept my answer please.

Comment: I mean. Opening another HTML code only to extract one particular line (between a lot of similar lines).

Comment: The "selected" line can be stored in a variable (that's up to you). After that you can treat it as a string and pass it etc etc

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot for your help, @pr1nc3

Answer (score 0):

As explained on [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) above

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname:9090/path?arg=value#anchor';

 function unparse_url($parsed_url) {
  $fragment = isset($parsed_url['fragment']) ? '#' . $parsed_url['fragment'] : '';
  return "$fragment";
} 
?>
```

will return

```
anchor
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and (very) dirty answer:

```
$data = '<a href="page1.html#num0035583725">name1</a>
<a href="page30.html#num0035584494">othername</a>
<a href="page55.html#num0035584859">word</a>
<a href="page132.html#num0035585496">wordname</a>
<a href="page133.html#num0035586039">datadata</a>
<a href="page203.html#num0035586647">fsdfasfas</a>';

preg_match_all("/#num(\d+)\">([^<]*)</", $data, $matches);
$search = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
print_r($search);
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [0035583725] => name1
    [0035584494] => othername
    [0035584859] => word
    [0035585496] => wordname
    [0035586039] => datadata
    [0035586647] => fsdfasfas
)
```

The regex scans for the occurrences of `#num` and then takes everything between `">` and `<` after that.

Did I already mention this is dirty? Regexes are a nasty way to parse XML. Better use some parser.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Matthijs. I'll try what you showed too. And how would you use some parser, if is not much to ask?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a regex for this. You can use an HTML parser to get the exact HREF, then use the URL parser get the fragment.

```
$string = '<a href="page1.html#num0035583725">name1</a>
<a href="page30.html#num0035584494">othername</a>
<a href="page55.html#num0035584859">word</a>
<a href="page132.html#num0035585496">wordname</a>
<a href="page133.html#num0035586039">datadata</a>
<a href="page203.html#num0035586647">fsdfasfas</a>';
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->LoadHTML($string, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($links as $link){
    if(strpos($link->nodeValue, 'name1') !== FALSE) {
        $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
        $url_bits = parse_url($href);
        echo $url_bits['fragment'];
    }
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/DNdE5

You could use a regex, explode, or preg_split on the `$href` here if for some reason the URL parser isn't working. A regex approach could be:

```
$string = '<a href="page1.html#num0035583725">name1</a>
<a href="page30.html#num0035584494">othername</a>
<a href="page55.html#num0035584859">word</a>
<a href="page132.html#num0035585496">wordname</a>
<a href="page133.html#num0035586039">datadata</a>
<a href="page203.html#num0035586647">fsdfasfas</a>';
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->LoadHTML($string, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($links as $link){
    if(strpos($link->nodeValue, 'name1') !== FALSE) {
        $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
        preg_match('/#\K.+/', $href, $fragment);
        echo $fragment[0];
    }
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/F5LND